# SSRS Report Viewer Toolbar Broken

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have just noticed that the toolbar in SSRS (with the page numbers, save/print etc) is slightly askew (see image). After doing some testing, this only happens when accessing a report using the server's FQDN (http://reports.domain.com/Reports/). If I use the netbios/short url (http://reports/Reports/) it works fine - can anyone guess as to why?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/810527/sql-server-reporting-services-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11 ?  PLEASE be sure to look at the tab that show `Workarounds`.

Comment: I have SSRS 2008 R2, can't upgrade unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to Internet Explorer and Add your site to Compatiblity View:

**Follow below steps:**
Internet Explorer > Setting > Compatiblity View Setting

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I might add the URL to our GPO for compatibility :)